# TPL with distinct filename using Datetime.Now

Tags: .net, datetime, concurrency, locking, task-parallel-library

I am uploading multiple files to a sftp server using tasks. But what is currently happening is that the same "fileName" is being generated when multiple tasks execute in parallel. I want to ensure a distinct filename is generated every time.

```
//Simplified version of my code:
processingTasks = 1000;
while (processingTasks > 0)
{
    processingTasks --;
    Task<string> task = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
          string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt";
          return UploadFileToSFTP(fileName, fileContent);
    });
}
```

Would the following work for me, giving me distinct datetime filenames or is there a better way to do this?

```
processingTasks = 1000;
while (processingTasks > 0)
{
     processingTasks --;
     Task<string> task = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
           lock(file) //Will only one task go inside this at a time?
           {
               Thread.Sleep(1000);
               string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt";
           }

           return UploadFileToSFTP(fileName, fileContent);
     });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can kind of use Emile's idea to generate a “unique timestamp”: return `DateTime.Now` if this time wasn't returned yet, otherwise return first free second in the future.

This way, you will get a timestamp that's incorrect by a small amount (or by a big amount, if you call this method more than once per second for a long time), but it means you don't have to wait, which feels fragile to me.

In code:

```
public static class UniqueTimestamp
{
    private static readonly object Lock = new object();
    private static DateTime LastTimestamp = DateTime.MinValue;

    private static DateTime RoundToSecond(DateTime dt)
    {
        return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day,
                            dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);
    }

    public static DateTime GetTimestamp()
    {
        var now = RoundToSecond(DateTime.Now);
        DateTime timestamp;
        lock (Lock)
        {
            if (now > LastTimestamp)
                timestamp = now;
            else
                timestamp = LastTimestamp.AddSeconds(1);
            LastTimestamp = timestamp;
        }
        return timestamp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. This worked and is a much faster solution than the thread.Sleep(1000), I was using.

Answer (score 1):

If two tasks execute within the same second then the filenames will not be unique. 
A solution would be to have a global (perhaps static) number generator.

```
public static class NumberGenerator
{
    static object syncObject = new Object();
    static int nextNr = 0;
    public static int NextNumber
    {
        get
        { 
            lock (syncObject)
            {
                nextNr++;
                return nextNr;
            }
        }
    }
}

string filename = NumberGenerator.NextNumber + ".txt";
```

Comment: I have to have a filename with **[datetime].txt** kind of format i.e. **20121219021320.txt** (yyyyMMddHHmmss.txt), so I cannot change the filename format. I can only ensure that the seconds in the filename are somehow different.
Would the locking, with a 1 second Thread.Sleep() in my code ensure that?

Comment: +1: but as Saad commented, a Thread.Sleep(1000) is probably required.

Answer (score 0):

You could incorporate the [Task.CurrentId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.currentid%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property into your filename.

Comment: The files uploaded are being used by another system, and the two systems have an agreed upon fileName format i.e. **20121219021320.txt** (yyyyMMddHHmmss.txt), so I cannot change the filename format.
I can only ensure that the seconds in the filename are different, and I was looking for a way to do this.